# Ant - Run several servers on different terminals in build.xml

Tags: java, ant

I want to write a buildfile that should open a new terminal for every client/server I want to use for testing.

How can I do that? I tried this code to run for example the 'ls' command on the newly created terminal. He created the terminal but doesn't run the cmd.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`exec` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html):

```
<exec executable="emacs">
  <env key="DISPLAY" value=":1.0"/>
</exec>
```

You should be able to open a terminal using either of the tags, and provide arguments similar to:

```
gnome-terminal --geometry 69x36+0+60 -x sh -c command_string
```

- `--geometry` : So that you don't have to rearrange the terminals at each startup
- `-x` : Execute the remainder of the command line inside the terminal.
- `sh -c` Start shell and read commands from the command_string operand instead of from the standard input.